# If I didn't have vs Hadn't I had. What's the difference?

Tags: difference, phrases

I took an English test where I had to complete sentences. After I finished the test I was told that my answer "If I didn't have..." was wrong and I should have written "Hadn't I had...".

That sentence:
"*Hadn't I had* the chance to make that acquaintance, I would never have been able to enjoy such a huge success."

Comment: That's wrong. Throw your test out and find a teacher who knows what they're talking about.

Answer (score 5):

If I'm understanding the context correctly, your answer isn't correct, because the action in the first part of the sentence ("have the chance to make that acquaintance") occurs (hypothetically) *before* the action in the second part ("be able to enjoy such a huge success), and provides the context for it - so the past perfect is appropriate ("If I hadn't had...").

It is also possible to phrase the sentence without "if", using inversion ("Had I not had...") to express the same meaning. However, contraction is not allowed in this construction, so your teacher's answer is also incorrect.